# How to insert data in db in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi i am trying to insert data in db in java.

i have 4 fields

```
s.no  city  mandi  price
```

s.no is primary key

i have a string

```
 S=1 Agra Achhnera NIL
    2 Agra Agra NIL
    3 Agra Fatehabad NIL
    4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL
    5 Agra Jagner NIL
    6 Agra Jarar NIL
    7 Agra Khairagarh NIL
    8 Agra Shamshabad NIL
    9 Aligarh Atrauli NIL
    10 Aligarh Chharra NIL
    11 Aligarh Aligarh 1300.00
    12 Aligarh Khair 1300.00;
```

i want to fill this string in table like this

```
 s.no        city       mandi         price
  1          Agra      Achhnera       NIL 
  2          Agra      Agra           NIL
  3          Agra      Fatehabad      NIL
  4          Agra      Fatehpur Sikri NiL
```

How can i achieve my desired out put?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask Google, he is good guy.

Comment: exact i need to fetch  values string and then insert into db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
   while(str.hasMoreElements()){
      for(int I=0;i<4;i++){
         int no = str.nextElement();
         String city = str.nextElement();
         String mandi = str.nextElement();
         String price = str.nextElement();
         //insert them into the database
      }
   }
```

Comment: i am getting error "object can not converted in to int,string"

Comment: int no = Integer.parseInt(str.nextElement.toString());
String city = str.nextElement().toString();

Comment: i am getting exception in this line "4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL"

Comment: Merge it using camelcase fatehpurSikri ;)

Comment: sory sir i tried regex but not able to achieve can u do this for me

Answer (score -1):

While moving ahead with jdbc, the first and the foremost step is to include the necessary jar file in your build (10g or 11g). Following this, we need to configure the connection class or you may call it DAO (Data Access Objects).

Now, it depends what technology you are working with. If i suppose we are working with Servlet's, so the ideal way is to have a clear distinction between your service class, the beans and your connection or DAO class.

You need get all your values from UI in your servlet class which may act as a controller and then call the method of your business class which will access the connection class and do the needful insert operations.

Link specified by user3382280 will be helpful. Go through it.

Just a suggestion, try to put down your business logic and connection logic in separate classes. Clear separation of logic is an ideal way to move forward for re-useability and flexibility in the code. Hope it helps :)